# Iptables block incoming traffic allow outgoing

Tags: linux, iptables

I've some trouble to configure iptables correctly. I Want to block all incoming traffic expect SSH and I want to allow any outgoing traffic. I executed the following.

```
#!/bin/sh

ETH0=$(ifconfig eth0 | grep 'inet addr:' | cut -d: -f2 | awk '{ print $1}')
ETH1=$(ifconfig eth1 | grep 'inet addr:' | cut -d: -f2 | awk '{ print $1}')


#!/bin/sh
# My system IP/set ip address of server

# Flushing all rules
iptables -F
iptables -X

# Setting default filter policy
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P FORWARD DROP

# Allow unlimited traffic on loopback
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o eht1 -j ACCEPT

# Allow incoming ssh only
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s 0/0 -d ${ETH1} --sport 513:65535 --dport 22 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -s ${ETH1} -d 0/0 --sport 22 --dport 513:65535 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

# make sure nothing comes or goes out of this box
iptables -A INPUT -j DROP
```

My output looks like this:

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     any     anywhere             anywhere            
   77  5588 ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             tcp spts:login:65535 dpt:ssh state NEW,ESTABLISHED
  224 13826 DROP       all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  any    lo      anywhere             anywhere            
   92  6993 ACCEPT     all  --  any    eth0    anywhere             anywhere            
   45  6340 ACCEPT     all  --  any    eth1    anywhere             anywhere            
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             tcp spt:ssh dpts:login:65535 state ESTABLISHED
```

The outbound traffic for eth0 and eth1 is allowed but its not working.

`wget http://www.google.com` will result in `Resolving www.google.com (www.google.com)...`
After a while i get the output `wget: unable to resolve host address`www.google.de'`

But where is the mistake in my configuration. How can I allow more than anything on outbound traffic?

Comment: You've blocked incoming DNS responses, which is why you can't resolve hostnames.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the commentator in the question suggests you have blocked DNS. 
You definitely need to allow for `RELATED` connections as well . So at least append that

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s 0/0 -d ${ETH1} --sport 513:65535 --dport 22 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

but for clarity this may look better:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s 0/0 -d ${ETH1} -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s 0/0 -d ${ETH1} --sport 513:65535 --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
```

also these

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o eht1 -j ACCEPT
```

are not necessary since the policy `-P` of your output chain is to `ACCEPT`.

Answer (score 5):

Add

```
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

to let established connections to get reply from the internet. And replace your two SSH lines with this one line

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s 0/0 -d ${ETH1} --dport 22 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT
```

as the first line already covers the established part of the ssh.

Answer (score 0):

By deffinition DNS is a client/server model. How can DNS server send you their answers if you just blocked all input. Allow establieshed connection traffic so you can receive the servers answers.